# regexp optimizer

Tags: regex

I have a big list of simple expressions (2Mb file). For example:
`11.*;112.*;113.*;12.*;123.*`

I need to remove unnecessary expressions and come up with this:
`11.*;12.*`

bash version would be appreciated. thanks in advance

Comment: Which expressions do you categorize as 'unnecessary'? All 3-digit numbered expressions?

Comment: @Chirag64: `11.*` already covers the case of `112.*` and `113.*`, `12.*` already covers the case of `123.*`. So simplified to `11.*;12.*`.

Comment: Please update your question with 1) The syntax of the expression (what feature do you use in the expression?) 2) What have you tried?

Comment: @Chirag64 the length of expressions differs much in file - from 2 digits to 7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is something in Perl that would work, *provided the only wildcards in your pattern are of the form `.*`*:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my %terms;
{
    local $/;
    %terms = map {$_ => 1} split /;|\n/, <>;
}

foreach my $k1 (keys %terms)
{
    foreach my $k2 (keys %terms)
    {
        if ($k1 ne $k2 and $k1 =~ /^$k2$/)
        {
            delete $terms{$k1};
            last;   
        }
    }   
}

print join ';', keys %terms;
```

It accepts your file as a command line argument.

This works by comparing keys to each other.  In each comparison, one key is treated as a string and the other key is evaluated as a regex.  This takes advantage of the fact the `.*` matches anything--including the literal characters `.*`. Thus an expression that matches the literal string of another pattern will also match all strings that pattern would match.

It will work even if there are multiple `.*` terms in a single pattern.  For example, it correctly determines that `1.*1.*` matches everything that `11.*` matches, deleting the latter.

However, this is kind of a hacky simplification and **will not** work if you introduce other regex patterns.  There is no easy solution to this problem *in general*, because you would have to parse all patterns and figure out what each would match.